# Javascript const arrow function

Tags: javascript, html, constants, arrow-functions

I know is kind of a dumb question but I'm kinda confused, tried to look up on the internet but couldn't find anything so..

when in JS (ES6) I declare an arrow function as `const`, how can I invoke it when page is loaded?

es.

```
const bigBla = async () => { bla bla };
```

tried smt like `onload="bigBla()"` but doesn't work, also tried to invoke it at the end of the JS file but won't work in the HTML file (need to change `innerHTML` of a span element/src of an `iframe`, data come from http request), whereas if i declare function `bigBla(){...}` and use `onload="bigBla()"` i have no problems. Help me :(

Comment: `const`s don't become automatic globals, so `onload` doesn't find it. I'd recommend `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', bigBla)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `window.onload` function in your javascript file.

```
window.onload = function() {
  bigBla();
};
```

Comment: i  still think that `window.onload = () => {` should work, but it does not.